# correct way of comparing string jquery operator =

Tags: jquery

Is this the correct way? I want the statement to run if the value of somevar equals the string?

```
if (somevar = '836e3ef9-53d4-414b-a401-6eef16ac01d6'){
 $("#code").text(data.DATA[0].ID);
}
```

Comment: No. That assigns the value. Use ===

Answer (score 51, accepted):

No. = sets somevar to have that value. use === to compare value and type which returns a boolean that you need.

Never use or suggest == instead of ===. its a recipe for disaster. e.g 0 == "" is true but "" == '0' is false and many more.

More information also in [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use)

Comment: Similarly, you may use `!==` instead of `!=` for checking opposite conditions.

Answer (score 10):

NO, when you are using only one "=" you are assigning the variable.

<strike>You must use "==" :</strike> You must use "===" :

```
if (somevar === '836e3ef9-53d4-414b-a401-6eef16ac01d6'){
 $("#code").text(data.DATA[0].ID);
}
```

You could use fonction like `.toLowerCase()` to avoid case problem if you want

Comment: == is bad practice in Javascript and should be avoided

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should use double "==" instead of "=" to compare two values. Using "=" You assigning value to variable in this case "somevar"

Comment: == is bad practice in Javascript and should be avoided